# Cucumber test.feature doesn't see my steps

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, gherkin

I wanted to start testing with cucumber, created the simpliest test.feature file:

```
Feature: XYZ
 Scenario: S1
  When I am on x page
  Then I see the element
```

and create steps

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

    public class MyStepdefs {
        @When("^I am on x page$")
        public void iAmOnXPage() {
            System.out.println("I'm on page");
        }

        @Then("^I see the element$")
        public void iSeeTheElement() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("I see dead people");
        }
    }
```

I've all needed plugins installed:
- Cucumber for Java
- Cucumber for Groovy
- Gherkin
Structure of files is:

[image]

Moreover the test/java folder is marked as Test Source Folder in Maven.
I also tried to restart IntelliJ and Reimport project in Maven, nothing helps. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found a solution, I created additional testRunner class:

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features={"src/test/resources"}
)

public class testRunner {
}
```

It wasn't mentioned in few tutorials I've checked but found it in https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/01/getting-started-with-bdd-intellij/
and after small changes (eg `@Cucumber.Options` -> `@CucumberOptions`) it worked:)